# Mockito How to test that an instance created inside a method is calling methods

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockito

Let's say I have this function:

```
fun method() {
   val obj = Obj()
   obj.callsMethod()
   obj.callsOtherMethod()
}
```

How can I do something similar to verify(obj).callsMethod()? Is there any other way I could test this method?

Comment: I don't think its possible. you can consider changing it to `fun method(obj: Obj = Obj())` always good to be able to 'inject' values if they need to be tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three alternatives:

1. Using the injection
2. Using [PowerMockito](https://powermock.github.io/)
3. Refactor the code in a test friendly manner

**Using the injection**

If the object Obj is injected in your class under test, instead of has been initialized in the method, you will be able to inject a mock and then use the expression

```
verify(obj).callsMethod()
```

that you already knew and that is right.

**Using PowerMockito**

With powermockito you can write something like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Obj.class})
class MyJunit{
....
@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
Obj myMock = Mockito.mock(Obj.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(Obj.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myMock);

// here your test
}
```

At this point you can use the expression you already knew and that is right.

**Refactor**

You can use a `protected` method in order to build th `Obj` and mock this method in your junit in order to return a mock version of the Obj and then use the expression you already knew and that is right.