# How to mock for new object initialized in a class java junit?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

How to mock for new object initialized in a method of a class? getting failure like "its failing like "Wanted but not invoked: invokeMyMethod() Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. ....." i have followed
an example "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito" . its not helping.

```
Class Login { //existing design. cannot change.

 private MyClass myclass; 

 public void init() {  
  myclass = new MyClass();
  myclass.invokeMyMethod();
 }

}

///Junit

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class LoginTest {

 @InjectMocks
 Login login;

 @Test
 void testInit() {

 Login spyObj = Mockito.spy(login);
 MyClass myclass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
 spyObj.init();
 verify(myclass).invokeMyMethod();// its failing like "Wanted but not invoked: invokeMyMethod() Actually, 
                                  //there were zero interactions with this mock.
}
```

}

Comment: The "myClass" you are mocking is different from the "myClass" being initialized inside init(). There is no way you can access that. You need to find a way to inject the "myClass" into Login. How about a setter?

Comment: its existing design. so unable to chage it. Thatswat I saw we can use spy . but that also not working.

Comment: You need to find a way to replace the "myClass" which is instantiated using `new MyClass()` with your mock object. Otherwise, there is no hope to verify its interactions.

Comment: But in this example "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920153/test-class-with-a-new-call-in-it-with-mockito" , using spy it will take care. can u help  the way to replace ?

Comment: Maybe this helps --> https://rieckpil.de/mock-java-constructors-and-their-object-creation-with-mockito/.

Comment: @shree That's different. The `login` method *returns* `LoginContext` there so they say instead of the actual returned value use the mocked `lcMock`.
But you may be able to use this solution of the same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/30137217/2400380

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69498486/4210091)

Answer (score 0):

You need PowerMock together with Mockito. But sadly it doesn't run with JUnit5.
If you can run your test with JUnit 4 the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352539/how-can-we-write-test-cases-for-socket-connections/70354236#70354236) gives you a point to start from.